# Update Varchar entries in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, date, varchar, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE `Schedule` (
  `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deptime` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3221 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The field `deptime` contains entries in the following format: `2012-09-04 09:17`.

Now I need to change the day of all entries in this field, i.e. `2013-07-01 09:17`. The time, i.e. `09:17` should not be changed. How can I do this in a quick way using some `UPDATE` query?

Comment: If you would use a `timestamp` or similar column type, this would be much easier!

Comment: @Sirko: The problem is that a have a predefined data set that was previously created for this table. I should use this data set, but the day must be modified. That's why I cannot re-define the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or try this...

```
    UPDATE schedule SET deptime = CONCAT('2013-07-01 ',TIME(deptime));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
update table Schedule 
set deptime = STR_TO_DATE(deptime,'%Y-%m-7 %h: %i');
OR
update table Schedule 
set deptime = STR_TO_DATE(deptime,'%Y-%m-$PHPVar %h: %i');
```

1) Give the hardcode value in day field or provide PHP variable if you have.
2) use %H for 24 hrs format and %h for 12 hrs format in str_to_date function